# How to find if diagonal lines intersect

Tags: geometry

If I know that there are n vertices in some regular n-gon, how can I find out if diagonals made from pairs of vertices intersect. I've tried thinking of it in terms of a square, hexagon, dodecagon, etc. Thanks!

Edit.

If I have three diagonals can I show that they intersect at the same point? So, lets say I have a hexagon, with three diagonals. Can I show that they intersect at the same point?

Comment: I don't understand your edit about three diagonals, but recommend you start a new question if you still need help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's color the two diagonals red and blue. Number you vertices consecutively, so that vertex 1 is one of the endpoints of the red diagonal.

Now consider the possible cases for the order in which you encounter the other colored vertices:

1. Red, blue blue. In this case the two diagonals don't intersect, because the red line doesn't "clip" either endpoint of the blue line.
2. Blue, red, blue. In this case the two diagonals *do* intersect: it is impossible to go from the first blue vertex to the second without crossing the red line.
3. blue, blue, red. This is a "mirrored" version of the first case, and again the diagonals don't intersect.

So if you number the red and blue vertices $r_1, r_2, b_1, b_2$, with $r_1 = 1$ and $b_1 < b_2$, then the diagonals intersect if

$$b_1 < r_2 < b_2.$$

The above assumes that the two diagonals don't share a vertex. It's not 100% clear whether or not two diagonals that share a vertex should be considered intersecting; if you decide they should, it's easiest to check for when the two diagonals do *not* intersect:
$$r_2 < b_1\quad \textrm{or}\quad b_2 < r_2.$$